# How can i make nested schema for a course with sub-topic and every sub-topic having Sub-topic Name, time duration, video URL in Sanity.io?

Tags: schema, sanity

**
I don't Know how to make this please help if possible or tell me where can i find some similar Schema
I want to create video lecturer website
with topic, sub-topic, time-duration
**

```
export default {
  name: "Courses",
  title: "Property",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      title: "Movie",
      name: "movie",
      type: "document",
      fields: [
        {
          title: "Title",
          name: "title",
          type: "string",
        },
        {
          title: "Poster",
          name: "poster",
          type: "image",
        },
        {
          title: "Sub-Topic",
          name: "directors",
          type: "array",
          of: [{ type: "string" }],
        },
        {
          title: "Video URL",
          name: "imageUrl",
          type: "url",
        },
        {
          title: "Rich text example",
          name: "myRichTextExample",
          type: "array",
          of: [{ type: "block" }],
        },
      ],
    },
```